# How to place columns of data set from excel file into numeric arrays

Tags: matlab

I have an excel file that I grab by:

```
ds = dataset('XLSFile',fullfile('file path here', 'waterReal.xlsx'))
```

It looks like this:

[image: Dataset content]

I want each column in its own numeric array though! Like how when I load an example dataset: load carsmall, I get a bunch of individual numeric arrays. But I can't figure out how to do that.

I can do this individually by writing:

```
A = ds.TEMP, B = ds.PROD, ...
```

Bu what if I had  BIG excel file? What then?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's better if you copy and paste your program output as text (inside triple-backticks) instead of as a screenshot. Screenshots are lousy to work with unless you're dealing specifically with GUI or graphics things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a dataset to a struct or a cell like this:

To struct:

```
s = dataset2struct(ds, 'AsScalar',true)
```

To cell:

```
fnames = fieldnames(ds);
c = cell(1, numel(fnames));
for i = 1:numel(fnames)
  c{i} = ds.(fnames{i});
end
```

By the way: use `table`s instead of `dataset`s. They're newer and better. Use the `readtable` function to read your Excel file into a table. And tables are nicer enough that you might not want to bother converting them into a simpler cell array, because you can just grab the columns out with `t{:,i}` where `t` is your table and `i` is the index of the column you want.